# Should i call InvokeLater inside a thread created in the EDT?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, event-dispatch-thread

what happens if i modify my gui inside a thread created in the edt?

When i say "created in the edt" i actually say that the thread declaration and its starts are in a block of code surrounded by:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

   public void run(){

      Thread t= new Thread(new Runnable(){

         public void run(){

            txtField.setText("setting...");
         }
      });

      t.start();
   }
}
```

will this modify my gui without side effects? or should i call again invokeLater inside Thread "T"?

Comment: It's a different thread from the EDT, therefore modifying swing components from it is not safe. So yes, you should call `invokeLater()` in `t`, if you need to access swing components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether you instantiate and run the thread in EDT. It will be a new thread, running independently from EDT, and therefore it will not be safe to modify the GUI from it. All Swing modifications must be done using `invokeLater()`.